# Emails with attachments come up empty using Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an e-mail with an attachment using [Nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer). No matter what I do, if I specify an `attachments` property, the e-mail comes up empty (no attachments, no html, no text). Sending an e-mail without any attachments works as expected. Here's the code I have so far:

```
transporter.sendMail({
    to: `${toTitleCase(i.nome)} <${i.email}>`,
    subject: 'Treinamentos',
    text: 'hello!',
    html: `Embedded image: <img src="cid:nyan@example.com"/>`,
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: 'newimg.jpg',
                path: __dirname + '/src/img/newimg.jpg',
                cid: 'nyan@example.com'
            }
        ]
    }, (err, info )=> {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(info);
    });
```

I have also tried using `content` instead of `path`, same result. I should also note that the `err` callback is empty.

Comment: You are missing at least one thing: `contentDisposition: 'inline'` in your file(s). Looking at a code of mine, I also add a key: `encoding: 'base64' ` (not sure if this is required)

Comment: Reffer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45388543/7635845

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe Not sure how that relates to my question, as I'm not even using Gmail. Either way, I figured out what was wrong and submitted it as an answer.

Comment: I didn't get your point!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had set `'Content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'` as the header on the `transporter` object. Removing that line fixed the issue.